# Counting cells and columns efficiently with a formula

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have the need to populate a table with the number of times a certain postal service was used, and for what region.

I have a big file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xNiE6hoLRyfuMOnUHTM0RjzeXCfCwvxn7ISAD3t4moA/edit?usp=sharing

I have created another tab in the spreadsheet called data, how do I count how many times a service was used, and correlate it to the correct region?

And how would I do this dynamically? Because I would not necessarily know beforehand the service or region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(PROPER(QUERY('2016-pf'!A2:B, 
 "select B,count(B) 
  where B is not null 
  group by B 
  pivot A", 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Amazing. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0):

In a new tab, in A1 try

```
=query('2016-pf'!A:B, "Select B, count(B) where B <>'' group by B pivot A", 1)
```

and see if that works for you?